# вопрос о sys.path: не находит импортируемую каталог

Tags: python

здравствуйте я не могу разобраться как работает sys.path.append(insert тоже пробовал не работает) мне нужно из database_main импортировать класс в logic_answer у меня есть такая структура каталогов:

```
\project
    \database
        \database_main.py
        \__init__.py
    \logic
        \logic_answer.py
    \main.py
```

в  logic_answer.py у меня сделано вот так:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(0, '..project\\database')
from database_main import * # я пробовал и from database.database_main import *
```

но это не работает.
можете подсказать в чём дело? 
заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё сделано не так

Во-первых, `sys.path.append()` принимает только один аргумент, а не два. Поэтому ваш код завершается ошибкой TypeError. Во-вторых, путь `..project\\database` не существует, т.к. поскольку не существует папка `..project`. Тут, видимо, пропущен знак разделителя.

Правильно должно быть

```
sys.path.append(r'..\project\database')
```